# Socket.io with 2 local machines?

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

I'm trying to use socket.io to send raspberry pi events from my express server.  I can't seem to get my raspberry pi to connect to the server though.  Any idea on what I'm doing wrong?

Rasberry Pi app:

```
  var socket = require('socket.io-client')('192.168.0.10:3000');
  console.log('running');
  socket.on('connect', function(){
    console.log('connected');
  });
  socket.on('event', function(data){
    console.log(data);
  });
  socket.on('disconnect', function(){
    console.log('disconnected');
  });
```

Express Server:

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendfile('index.html');
});

io.emit('event', 'hello');

io.on('connection', function(socket){
  console.log('a user connected');
});
io.on('disconnect', function(socket){
  console.log('a user disconnected');
});
http.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Needed to change the first line of my Raspberry Pi to include **http://**

**From :**

```
var socket = require('socket.io-client')('192.168.0.10:3000');
```

**TO:**

```
var socket = require('socket.io-client')('http://192.168.0.10:3000');
```